# convert string to time using culture info and store in SQL

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, c#-4.0

Hai friend i need to convert a string to time format using this code becauseit only support for cloud DB but its not working please dome one help me my duration value is **13:22:00** it is 24 hours format

```
Group.DurationPerDayAndMactch = TimeSpan.ParseExact(Duration,"hh:mm:ss",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: What's the data type in your database? I don't think most databases have a particular type to represent "duration".

Comment: Not sure why this is jQuery related?

Comment: time(0) datatype only i m using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New answer just using TimeSpan**

The problem is that `:` isn't recognized within the custom `TimeSpan` format specifier. You need to escape it. At that point, the culture really isn't relevant at all, so I'd specify the invariant culture, personally:

```
TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, "hh':'mm':'ss",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Personally I find it irritating that `:` *isn't* recognized... but that's a matter for the BCL team.

**Original answer**

Personally I'd use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, which aims to be a generally better date/time library for .NET. You can then parse it as a `Duration`, and convert that to a `TimeSpan` if you need to:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "13:12:34";

        DurationPattern pattern = 
            DurationPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("H:mm:ss");
        // TODO: Consider error handling. The ParseResult<T> returned by
        // pattern.Parse helps with that.
        Duration duration = pattern.Parse(input).Value;
        TimeSpan timeSpan = duration.ToTimeSpan();
        Console.WriteLine(timeSpan);
    }
}
```

(Alternatively, you could just store the number of ticks in the duration.)

Note that I've used the invariant culture here - that's usually more appropriate when you're specifying an exact pattern.

You *could* use the current culture, but it would only affect the time separator (`:` in the invariant culture) in the pattern you're providing.

Comment: I dnt have nodatime referance there is any other way to solve this

Comment: @Dinesh: I've actually just worked out what's wrong with your original code - editing now.

Comment: This is an error (System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format) but my input is 11:33:00 i dont know what is the problem and my database datatype is time(0)

Comment: @Dinesh: The *exact* code I've given (at the top) works with that input. Are you sure you copied my code exactly, and that your input doesn't have leading or trailing whitespace? Personally I wouldn't use `time` for this - you're not trying to record a time of day, you're trying to record a period of time. They're not the same thing.